# AngularJS directive: Why I get ''TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON"?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

The directive works fine but I keep getting this error in browser console.

HTML:

```
<ms-search-pager filtered-items="batches | searchBatch:searchString" skip-items="skipItems" show-items="showItems" search-string="searchString"></ms-search-pager>
```

msSearchPager.js:

```
app.directive('msSearchPager', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/app/templates/directives/msSearchPager.html',
        scope: {
            filteredItems: '=',
            skipItems: '=',
            showItems: '=',
            searchString: '='
        }
    }
});
```

msSearchPager.hmtl:

```
<span>
    <span>
        <input data-ng-model="searchString" data-ng-change="skipItems=0" type="search" />
        <input data-ng-model="showItems" type="text"/>
        <a>{{Math.min(skipItems+1, filteredItems.length)}} to {{Math.min(skipItems + showItems, filteredItems.length)}} of {{filteredItems.length}}</a>
    </span>
</span>
```

So, why the circular error? How to fix it?

UPDATE: 
As requested, I created a Plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/LBXeqA5zL2dH5Zjlu6h1

Comment: Can you reproduce that in Plunker/Fiddler?

Comment: I get other type of error

Comment: In fact, I got 5 errors each time. The first three are same "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON". The forth is "Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!". The fifth is "Uncaught Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!". I don't know why I didn't get the first three in Plunker. But I guess they come from the same source.

Comment: are you using requirejs?

Comment: No, I'm not using requirejs.